# how to create custome alexa skill in c# and get response on my laptop

Tags: alexa-skills-kit, alexa-voice-service

I want to create custom Alexa skill in C# and try to get response on my laptop for running any application.
So user can ran any application by sending commands using Alexa dot.

Comment: Hi Mubashar - are you using a C# standalone server, or a C# Lambda?

Comment: I am using C# lambda for testing purpose.

Answer (score 2):

Alexa needs the endpoints to support SSL. The usual approach here is to setup https://ngrok.com/ to tunel to your laptop and run your own application server to handle the commands. This tutorial uses RoR but the idea is the same: https://echobind.com/blog/alexa-custom-skills-with-account-linking/

Comment: Thanks Josep vallas for your help. I will come back to you if I found any Trouble. Thanks again. you rely gave me direction.